# Why SharedPreferences not throw Exceptions?

Tags: android, xml, file, sharedpreferences

Shared preferences in android uses XML file to read/write data, then why does they not throw exceptions which are thrown if we use File instead of SharedPreferences.

Example code to read data from file. We have to catch exception.

```
 private void readFile(Context context){
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis= context.openFileInput("FileName"); // open file for reading
        fis.read(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

    } catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

Example code to read data from SharedPreferences. No need to catch exception.

```
 private void readSharedPreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String testRead = settings.getString("sample", "");
    // above statement does not throw IOException.(however it reads from file).
}
```

Comment: which type of file did you use instead of SharedPreferences?

Comment: if we use FileOutputStream then it throws FileNotFound Exception, if file by that name is not present. Then if we write data to file then it throws IOException

Comment: how are the shared preferences related to your question? Please provide your code with the error you're getting

Comment: I am not getting any error, I am just curious about how shared preferences manage exceptions (as they use file under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

Well, SharedPreferences can actually throw an IOException, but why should they make the code such that that happens all the time?
If you want to know what's under the hood, just take a look at the sourcecode: [SharedPreferences.Java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java) and [ContextImpl.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java)
.

Comment: Ok, if they can actually throw an IOException, then plz tell the scenario when it is thrown.

Comment: Well that wouldn't be different from any other IOException. Easiest attempt would be to make the filesystem have no free space left, then try to write a new settings file. Other options you could try include modifying the android OS, or corrupting the storage controller of your phone.